# What exactly does "lock" do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was writing a Perl script and noticed that my editor highlighted the word "lock."  I was curious so I looked up what "lock" does in Perl and have been unable to find a straightforward answer (at least not one that I could fully understand).

This is the best answer I found:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lock.html

---

ex: lock *THING*

"places an advisory lock on a shared variable or referenced object contained in *THING* until the lock goes out of scope."

---

What exactly does this mean?  The "lock" function isn't used to lock files because everything I have read says to use "flock" for that, so what is "lock" used for?  Does it have to do with threading and making sure multiple processes running at the same time don't bump into each other?

Comment: See [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=579444) for some info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's primary purpose is for multithreading. It locks a shared variable, such that if any other thread tries to `lock` it, then the `lock` call will block until it is released.

To illustrate:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $lock_var : shared;

sub worker_thread {
    print threads -> self -> tid(). ": Waiting for lock\n";
    lock ( $lock_var );
    print threads -> self -> tid(). ": got lock, doing some pretend code\n";
    sleep rand(10);
    #lock released when out of scope.
}

for ( 1..10 ) {
    threads -> create ( \&worker_thread );
}

foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) {
    $thr -> join();
}
```

You can either use it for resource control, to create a mutual exclusion, or you can use it to lock e.g. a hash when you want to update it without another thread doing so at the same time.

You should note though - the `lock` is not enforced. You can still modify the shared variable despite the `lock`. It's only the `lock` function call that'll test if the variable is currently unlocked.

When you're doing a variable manipulation, it's important to use `lock`. Any test where you `read->change->write` you can create a race condition if you don't lock - you cannot be certain that between the read and write, another thread won't do the same.

You may want to also look at `Thread::Semaphore` which does something similar.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of file locking, of which you appear to have some knowledge:

- When you do `flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;`, it'll block until it obtains a lock on that file. No two handles can hold a lock on that file at the same time.
- When you do `lock $var;`, it'll block until it obtains a lock on that shared variable. No two threads can hold a lock on that shared variable at the same time.

As you can see, both provide a means of providing mutual access to some arbitrary resources.

Notes:

- Shared variables exist within a process, so `lock $var;` only provides synchronicity within a process. But it also means it doesn't need to use any named external resources (e.g. a file).